# how to check a function in an injected controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, unit-testing, jasmine

i'm currently just trying to test if *getTodaysHours* function on my controller has been called. ultimately the function should get *hours* from the mock JSON *data* and pass if parameters match, but i'm stuck on the first part.

vendor.controller

```
export class VendorController {
    constructor($rootScope, data, event, toastr, moment, _, distanceService, vendorDataService, userDataService, stateManagerService) {
        'ngInject';
        //deps
        this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
        this.toastr = toastr;
        this._ = _;
        this.userDataService = userDataService;
        this.vendorDataService = vendorDataService;
        this.stateManagerService = stateManagerService;
        this.event = event;

        //bootstrap
        data.isDeepLink = true;
        this.data = data;
        this.data.last_update = moment(this.data.updated_at).format('MM/DD/YY h:mm A');
        this.data.distance = distanceService.getDistance(this.data.loc.lng, this.data.loc.lat);
        this.data.todaysHours = this.getTodaysHours();
        this.data.rating_num = Math.floor(data.rating);


        this.hasReviewed = (userDataService.user.reviewed[data._id]) ? true : false;
        this.isGrid = false;
        this.isSearching = false;
        this.hideIntro = true;
        this.menuCollapsed = true;
        this.filterMenuCollapsed = true;

        this.selectedCategory = 'All';
        this.todaysHours = '';
        this.type = '';
        this.searchString = '';

        this.reviewScore = 0;

        this.today = new Date().getDay();

        this.vendorDataService.currentVendor = data;

        //load marker onto map
        $rootScope.$broadcast(event.ui.vendor.pageLoad, data);

        //get menu
        vendorDataService.getVendorMenu(data._id)
            .then((res)=> {
                this.data.menu = res.menu;
                this.menuContainer = this.data.menu;
                this.totalResults = this.getTotalResults();
                this.availableMenuCategories = this.getAvailableMenuCategories();
            })
            .catch(() => {
                this.toastr.error('Whoops, Something went wrong! We were not able to load the menu.',  'Error');
            });
    }

    //get todays hours
    getTodaysHours() {
        let today = this.data.hours[new Date().getDay()];
        return (today.opening_time || '9:00am') + ' - ' + (today.closing_time || '5:00pm');
    }  
}
```

the first test passes when I mock the JSON data with *$provide constant*

```
describe('vendor controller', () => {
    let vm,
        data = {"_id":"56b54f9368e685ca04aa0b87","lat_lon":"33.713018,-117.841101","hours":[{"day_of_the_week":"sun","closing_time":" 7:00pm","opening_time":"11:00am","day_order":0,"id":48880},...];

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('thcmaps-ui', ($provide) => {
        $provide.constant('data', new data);
      }));

    //first test
    it('should pass', () => {
        expect(data._id).toEqual('56b54f9368e685ca04aa0b87');
    });

    //second test
    it('should call getTodaysHours', () => {
    expect(vm.getTodaysHours()).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

then I tried to inject the controller (not sure if correct syntax):

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.module('thcmaps-ui', ($provide) => {
    $provide.constant('data', new data);
  }));
beforeEach(inject(($controller) => {
    vm = $controller('VendorController');
    spyOn(vm,'getTodaysHours').and.callThrough();
}));
```

and it gives me some kind of forEach error. the second test gives me a undefined error when evaluating vm.getTodaysHours():

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) vendor controller should pass FAILED
>       forEach@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:341:24
>       loadModules@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4456:12
>       createInjector@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4381:22
>       workFn@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2507:60
>       /Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4496:53
>
> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) vendor controller should call getTodaysHours FAILED
>       forEach@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:341:24
>       loadModules@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4456:12
>       createInjector@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4381:22
>       workFn@/Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2507:60
>       /Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4496:53
>       TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'vm.getTodaysHours') in /Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/.tmp/serve/app/index.module.js (line 9)
>       /Users/adminuser/Documents/workspace/thcmaps-ui/.tmp/serve/app/index.module.js:9:244419

Comment: If you're correctly mocking the controller, then you should be be getting the second error. Quite why you're getting the first error however, I'm not sure. Are you certain that there are no mistakes within your controller definition? If you could reproduce this error inside a Plunker, I could iron it out for you, but otherwise, you'll be on your own.

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the dependencies of your controller when instantiating it with `$controller`. For example, consider the following controller:

```
class MyController {
  constructor($rootScope, $log) {
    // Store the controllers dependencies
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.$log = $log;
  }

  // Return obituary value from the $rootScope
  getValue() {
    this.$log.debug('Retrieving value');
    return this.$rootScope.foobar;
  }

  // Get the current date
  getDate() {
    this.$log.debug('Getting date');
    return Date.now()
  }

  static get $inject() {
    return ['$scope', '$log'];
  }
}
```

> I've written this controller using ES6, note that the dependencies are defined within the static `$inject`getter at the foot of the class declaration. This will be picked up by AngularJS upon instantiation.

As you can see, the controller depends upon the `$rootScope` and the `$log` provider. When mocking this controller for testing purposes, you must inject the controllers dependencies like this:

```
describe('Spec: MyController', () => {
  var controller;

  beforeEach(inject(($rootScope, $log, $controller) => {
    controller = $controller('MyController', {
      $rootScope,
      $log
    });
  });

  it('should return a value from the $rootScope', () => {
    var value = controller.getValue();
    // ... perform checks
  });

  it('should return the current date', () => {
    var date = controller.getDate();
    // ... perform checks
  });
});
```

> More recent versions of Jasmine enable developers to leverage the `this` keyword throughout their tests.
>
> Any `beforeEach`, `afterEach`, and `it` declarations will all share the same reference to `this`, allowing you to avoid creating enclosed variables (like `var controller`, as seen above) and also avoid creating unnecessary globals. For example:
>
> ```
> beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $log, $controller) {
>   this.controller = $controller('MyController', {
>     $rootScope,
>     $log
>   });
> });
>
> it('should return a value from the $rootScope', function () {
>   this.value = controller.getValue();
>   // ... perform checks
> });
> ```

Note the second argument in the call to `$controller`, this must be an object containing the expected dependencies that your controller ('MyController', in this case) relies upon.

The reasoning behind this is simply to allow developers to pass mock services, factories, providers, etc to the controller as an alternative to spies.

---

- `$controller`: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing
- `this`: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

> Apologies for the unuseful link to the Jasmine documentation regarding the usage of `this` with tests, I couldn't add a direct link to the correct section of the page due to how their anchor tags are set out (the anchor tag contains a `<code></code>` block, doh!).

Comment: thanks Iain, I injected the dependencies and still getting the same errors my *beforeEach* looks like this now: https://jsfiddle.net/3bj4tg9d/

Comment: Could you please add the errors that you're getting to the question, the above code should work without any issues. There are most likely issues with your source, rather than you tests.